# rich:componentControl and setPropertyActionListener wont work together

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

```
<h:commandLink action="#" value="some value">
 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{someBean.id}" value="#{var.id}"/>
 <rich:componentControl target="popup" operation="show" />
 </h:commandLink>
```

Anybody has idea why this composition wont work. To be precise property action listener
does not do a job, and popup panel was shown. When I do something like this

```
<h:commandLink action="#{someBean.someAction}" value="some value">
 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{someBean.id}" value="#{var.id}"/>
 </h:commandLink>
```

property action listener works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It will work fine if you use `a4j:CommandButton` and use `oncomplete` attribute of this tag and invoke

```
 oncomplete=" #{rich:component('panelid')}.show();"
```